How to manipulate with time at Expect/TCL scripts
I'm working on integration tests, now there is a need to introduce the ability to manage time. I want to use libfaketime, but something is going wrong.
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/faketime/libfaketime.so.1
export FAKETIME=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
export FAKETIME_DONT_RESET=1

./test.exp

That's an example of sh file, that i'm using to launch any tests.
I want to replace the sleep command with rewind time like this:
set env(FAKETIME) "+50s" and time really changed, when I used debug to check current time, but that wasnt enough to work in our kernel, which launching in every test

Are you wanting to affect Tcl/Expect's own understanding of time or the understanding of time in some program that is being controlled?

@DonalFellows It turns out that we need to try to add it to the program itself. Before we start testing, we spawn our kernel, in which the tests are already running. I also tried to add the variable "LD PRELOAD" to the kernel spawn function itself, but it didn't help.
